# Bootstrap - Switching between Div with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm using bootstrap as my responsive framework and I have a container, row I  also have two div's that I'm going to be switching between using a button. So I setup my HTML and my second div I set the display to "none" to hide it. However when using Jquery fadeIn/fadeOut you can see there is some shifting/expanding in terms of the Height.

Now I think to get around this I have to set the position to Absolute and also change the z-index of the first and second div so one is hidden behind the other. Using absolute however breaks the bootstrap container... So is there a way to switch the Div without the shifting in height when the button is clicked. Added some source so you can see what happens when to buttons are clicked.

http://www.bootply.com/hBNIHfCpxR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.bootply.com/PIG2icyErI

Relevant CSS:

```
.row {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
  }

#content-one, #content-two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```